# QT Creator - "No matching signal for" with deleted elements

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am getting these warning messages but I deleted the objects it warned me about. I am confused why it keeps bringing these messages up. Moreover, this is causing a bug where I have specified a signal for a push-button, but it does not do its function (I even set a debug log message if it were pressed).

in my moc_mainwindow.cpp file I noticed these lines of code:

```
static const qt_meta_stringdata_MainWindow_t qt_meta_stringdata_MainWindow = {
{
    QT_MOC_LITERAL(0, 0, 10), // "MainWindow"
    QT_MOC_LITERAL(1, 11, 22), // "on_radioButton_clicked"
    QT_MOC_LITERAL(2, 34, 0), // ""
    QT_MOC_LITERAL(3, 35, 26), // "on_exitRadioButton_clicked"
    QT_MOC_LITERAL(4, 62, 21), // "on_pushButton_clicked"
    QT_MOC_LITERAL(5, 84, 18) // "on_exitBtn_clicked"

},
"MainWindow\0on_radioButton_clicked\0\0"
"on_exitRadioButton_clicked\0"
"on_pushButton_clicked\0on_exitBtn_clicked"
};
```

which may have to do with the warning messages:

> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_radioButton_clicked()
> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_exitRadioButton_clicked()
> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_clicked()

any help is gladly appreciated :)

Comment: Does `clean` -> `run qmake` -> `rebuild` help?

Comment: no, if anything, it backtracked some progress

Comment: Does these slots exist: `on_radioButton_clicked`, `on_exitRadioButton_clicked`, `on_pushButton_clicked`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the build folder (the whole thing), and build the project again. I suggest a switch to cmake with Ninja - it won’t have such problems.

You have obsolete signal/slot connections in UI files - the `.ui.h` headers are where `connectSlotsByName` is invoked. So simply Greg your entire source folder for the names of the signals (Ctrl-Shift-F in Qt Creator), include all file types, and you’ll likely find those names inside the connections element in the `.ui` Xml files. They can be removed from there manually, or using the Designer built into Qt Creator.

Deleting the build folder is the starting point - you can’t afford to have any old state, and the “Clean” option in the IDE doesn’t do that last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging around I found the issue. It seems that it doesn't delete the slots which are located in the 'mainwindow.h' file. I need to delete these:

[image]

After running the application again, it then removes 'QT_MOC_LITERAL' that aren't being used (i.e deleted UI elements) as mentioned above (in the question) in the 'moc_mainwindow.cpp' file.

Comment: What does it mean _after some digging around I found the issue_? I told you that.

Comment: @scopchanov when? also, I just looking around the files and removing things, looking at the errors. you know....debugging...

Comment: @scopchanov I just looked at it, and frankly, it doesn't even help. It's like asking me if I got the warning messages that I said. I probably should have prefaced that I was new to QT Creator, so I hardly know where most of the things are. Thanks anyways though

Comment: _It's like asking me if I got the warning messages that I said_ No, it was a hint where to look.

Comment: @scopchanov ...so yea, it doesn't help if it is a "hint". I wanted answers, not a guessing game. And yes, figuring it out on my own is better than being told the answer, but this is not a school; this is a platform where one can ask questions and get answers. I honestly learn from these answers too since this error will likely occur again. It's okay if you don't feel that way, but this is just my opinion. Some people are better helpers than others :)

Comment: It was not a guessing. I should not assume anything. You have to provide this information with a [mcve], which you did not. That is why I needed to ask you about the details, pointing out possible causes. In any case, read about [ask].

Comment: Understandably, you are right. I didn't provide the best question, but I thought people on here would have a decent IQ for something as simple as asking for more information. I don't typically ask questions here, much less on online forums, but as a novice, this is how I learn and grow. :) we should probably stop filling the comment section.

Comment: I have an engineering and a PhD degree and have prepared hundreds of students for the industry. Probably I have _a decent IQ_. Still, I should not assume anything about your use case. It is your responsibility as the one, who is asking the question, to provide the required information.